# How to convert January 1, 2008 in c# datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have string that is in format January 1, 2008

how can I parseExact it to DateTime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A format string of "MMMM d, yyyy" should work. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "January 1, 2008";

        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "MMMM d, yyyy",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
}
```

Note that the culture is important here, in order to match the right month names. (I usually find the invariant culture handy, but only for situations where it matches requirements, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand you can use the simple way:

```
 string dateString = "January 1, 2008";

 DateTime parseValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

Or the exact, extended way:

```
 CultureInfo englishCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-EN");
 string dateString = "January 1, 2008";
 string formatString = "MMMM d, yyyy";

 DateTime extendedWay = DateTime.ParseExact(
     dateString,
     formatString,
     englishCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```